# How do I convert audio from the command line a la ImageMagick?

Tags: command-line, audio, conversion

ImageMagick is a handy, powerful command-line tool that can crop, scale, rotate, change format, apply basic (and some not-so-basic) effects to pretty much all sorts of images.

How can I join audio tracks, adjust levels, and transcode formats from the command line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, it's called [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)

*SoX is a cross-platform (Windows, Linux, MacOS X, etc.) command line utility that can convert various formats of computer audio files in to other formats. It can also apply various effects to these sound files, and, as an added bonus, SoX can play and record audio files on most platforms.*

Answer (score 3):

Another Soft:  [**moo0 ffmpeg converter**](http://www.moo0.com/?top=http://www.moo0.com/software/FFmpeg/)  -  converts audio files using CMD (command line).

i.e.:

```
c:\folder\bin\ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp3
```

Comment: I used ffmpeg for batch-conversion of video files for a web site. Good tool for power users. It can also handle audio.